# Carousel - Reduce the space between the items

Tags: android, carousel

I have some images displaying using carousel effect:

Here is the code:

** carousel_main.xml **

```
    <com.digitalaria.gama.carousel.Carousel
        android:id="@+id/carousel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

** carousel_item.xml **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/itemImage" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"    
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

java file:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.carousel_main);

    init();
    }

private void init() {
// create the carousel object.
carousel = (Carousel) findViewById(R.id.carousel);

// configurations for the carousel.
carousel.setType(Carousel.TYPE_COVERFLOW);
carousel.setOverScrollBounceEnabled(true);
carousel.setInfiniteScrollEnabled(false);
carousel.setItemRearrangeEnabled(true);

// set images for the carousel.
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
carousel.setAdapter(adapter);

// change the first selected position.
carousel.setCenterPosition(3);
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return musicCover.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return musicCover[position];
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.carousel_item, parent, false);
        view.setLayoutParams(new Carousel.LayoutParams(450, 450));

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);

        view.setTag(holder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(musicCover[position]);

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
    }
```

[image]

In the image you can see that there is lot of space between the left, middle and right (the black space).

What is happening is if i increase the size of the `view.setLayoutParams(new Carousel.LayoutParams(450, 450));`  to 600,600 then the left and right items will not be visible.

How to solve this?.

Comment: As you are increasing the height and width of the layout which you are inflating in your adapter class that is why it strach that much and occupies the space so that other left and right items is not visible.

Comment: @GrIsHu yes, but it should not happen, in Ios its not like this?, any clue how to solve this?

Comment: Do not set any layout parameters just keep it as it is.

Comment: i tried that its still the same @GrIsHu

Comment: Try to change its styles other than coverflow in `carousel.setType(Carousel.TYPE_COVERFLOW);`